# How to hide php extension in url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to remove php extension from url, But its not working for me. I am using Windows 7, with apache2.2.17 and php5.3. Now I have configured it as

in .htaccess file

```
OPTIONS -Indexes
IndexIgnore *

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

in httpd.conf enabled mod_rewrite as

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and

```
<Directory "D:/Apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

in php.ini

```
expose_php = On
```

After making these configuration still i am not able to remove php extension from url in my windows machine but same thing is working in ubuntu server.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might answer your question:

> RewriteRule ^/([^-]*)$  /$1.php

It works for root catalog.

> RewriteRule ^catalog/([^-]*)$  catalog/$1.php

Or you can write automatic script:

> RewriteRule ^/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$  /$1/$2.php

But this is for "httpd.conf" file.

Where: ([^-]*) means variable; $1, $2 means converted to variable i.e.

www.verity.com/foo/bar => verity.com/foo/bar.php

Comment: its working fine on ubuntu server, but not on my windows machine, Is there some configuration difference?

Comment: That was set up ON Windows Machine. 
I am using currently **Windows Server 2008**, with **Apache 2.2.22 _no-ssl_ **. Please wait, till I check config.
**EDIT**: Only httpd.conf file was modified. Nothing else. I will check other possibilities. Probably Apache is **too old**.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php
```

By doing this, you will be able to call example.com/abc.php as example.com/abc